# Mocha Requires me to read HTTP Request Body

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm attempting to use [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) to write tests for a Node.js API I'm working on.  The current tests I'm writing are only interested to see if responses are coming back with the correct status code - they do not care about the response body.

As such, I have written the following test:

*Note, this isn't the real test.  I've cut out the project-specific stuff.  The error **does** still occur on the code below.*

```
var http = require('http');
var assert = require("assert");

before(function() {
    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.end();
    }).listen(8080);
});

describe("Convenience Functions", function() {

    it("should return a 200 status code", function(done) {
        http.get("http://localhost:8080", function(res) {

            assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200);

            res.on('end', function() {

                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Running that test, however, gives me a timeout from Mocha.  Mocha defaults to a 2000ms timeout, but I could change that to any unnecessarily high number and it would still timeout.

I've been fighting with this for hours, and have finally found a "fix".  If I change the test to:

```
describe("Convenience Functions", function() {

    it("should return a 200 status code", function(done) {
        http.get("http://localhost:8080", function(res) {

            assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200);

            res.on('data', function() { })

            res.on('end', function() {

                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

the test no longer times out.  You will notice that the *only* difference between these two tests is that the second version is handling the `data` event on the response.  It doesn't do anything with the data, it just defines a listener on it.  Now my test passes with flying colors.

This is an easy enough fix to make, but I'm very confused as to *why* I need to do this.  Shouldn't mocha tests just finish as soon as I call `done()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   http.get("http://localhost:8080", function(res) {
      assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200);
      done();
   });
```

That's all you need. The data/end events would only be useful if the response had a body, but it doesn't and in any case you don't care, so just call `done()` and ignore the response other than checking it's status code.

> Shouldn't mocha tests just finish as soon as I call done()?

Yes, and they do. The problem in your first snippet is the `end` event never fires so you don't actually ever call `done()`.

Comment: That's super interesting that node doesn't call the end event unless you bind to the data event.  I guess it *kind of* makes sense.. But not entirely.

Comment: Yeah I suspect the whole streams1, streams2, streams3 whackiness is also at play there, but I don't have all the cases memorized in terms of what triggers the different behavior modes.